# remove elements from a list by exclusion

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame in which every row is a list. Is it possible to remove certain values from the column by exclusion?

I have tried the following approach for vectors:

```
yelp_asian_final %>% mutate(categories = ifelse(categories != "Thai" | categories != "Vietnamese", NULL, 
categories))
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: replacement has length zero.
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Example of the first 4 rows:

```
> dput(head(yelp_asian_final$categories,4)
+ )
list(c("Thai", "Restaurants"), c("Vietnamese", "Restaurants"), 
    c("Indian", "Restaurants"), c("Restaurants", "Japanese", 
    "Sushi Bars"))
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
 unnest() %>% 
 filter(v2 != 'Thai'& v2 != 'Vietnamese') %>% 
 nest(v2)
```

which gives,

> ```
>   v1                              data
> 1  1               Indian, Restaurants
> 2  5 Restaurants, Japanese, Sushi Bars
> 3  6                       Restaurants
> 4  9                       Restaurants
> ```